# Oracle SQL use subquery value in another subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Before I go any further please mind that I am not well experienced with SQL.

I have one query that is getting a single value (netto value) such as:

```
WITH cte_value_net AS (
    SELECT
        nvl(min(value_net),0) as value_net
    FROM (
        SELECT
            i.serial as serial,
            nvl(lag(i.value_net) OVER (PARTITION BY i.serial ORDER BY i.month), i.value_net) as value_net
        FROM 
            inventory i
        WHERE 
            i.ctypde IN (
                SELECT
                    ctypde
                FROM
                    appar ap
                WHERE 
                    ap.serial = in_serial -- this is the variable I want to set
            )
        AND 
            i.month IN (to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM'), to_char(add_months(sysdate, -2), 'YYYYMM'))
        AND
            i.serial = in_serial -- this is the variable I want to set
    ) vn
    GROUP BY vn.serial
)
```

In here I have to feed in the variable `in_serial` that I thought I could get from another subquery such as:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT * FROM cte_value_net) AS value_net
FROM (
    SELECT
        lap.serial AS in_serial
    FROM
        applap lap
)
```

but I can not wrap my head around it why this `in_serial` is not visible to my custom CTE. Could someone explain me how can I propagate the value from subquery like this?

The error I am obviously getting is:

```
SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "IN_SERIAL"
```

Unfortunately I do not have any sample data. What I want to achieve is that I could feed in the returned `in_serial` from main subquery to my CTE.

Before I can get `value_net` I need my main query to return the `in_serial`, otherwise I do not have access to that value.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  A non-working query is not particularly informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick I use is to produce an extra CTE that I usually call `params` that includes a single row with all computed parameters. Then, it's a matter of performing a `CROSS JOIN` with this CTE in any other CTE, subquery or main query, as needed.

For example:

```
with
params as ( -- 1. Create a CTE that returns a single row
  select serial as in_serial from applap
),
cte_value_net AS (
  select ...
  from inventory i
  cross join params -- 2. cross join against the CTE anywhere you need it
  where ...
    and i.serial = params.in_serial -- 3. Use the parameter
)
select ...
```

Comment: What would you do if the main select would join multiple tables? Such as: `SELECT lap.serial AS in_serial, bar.foo FROM bar JOIN applap lap ON lap.serial = bar.serial`

Comment: @Lisek I would again use a `CROSS JOIN` as in `SELECT params.in_serial, bar.foo FROM bar CROSS JOIN params`. Since `params` has a single row a cross join won't produce more rows but keep the ones that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

First, your second query is not syntactically correct, as there's a ',' before the FROM. You can write your query like this:

```
WITH cte_value_net AS (
    SELECT
        serial, nvl(min(value_net),0) as value_net
    FROM (
        SELECT
            i.serial as serial,
            nvl(lag(i.value_net) OVER (PARTITION BY i.serial ORDER BY i.month), i.value_net) as value_net
        FROM 
            inventory i
        WHERE 
            i.ctypde IN (
                SELECT
                    ctypde
                FROM
                    appar ap
                WHERE 
                    ap.serial = i.serial
            )
        AND 
            i.month IN (to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM'), to_char(add_months(sysdate, -2), 'YYYYMM'))
    ) vn
    GROUP BY vn.serial
)
select ...
from cte_value_net s join applap lap on (lap.serial=s.serial)
```

(adjust query to your schema ....)

Comment: No, I can not do it that way. You missed second AND caluse.

Comment: Did you try my solution and compare to the one you accepted to see if you have the same results?